# Need clarifications on adding regions dynamically in Marionette

Tags: marionette

I have an application where I need to display metrics.  The application needs to display a separate vertical section for each metric.  When I started this, there were only 5 metrics so I naively created a template with 5 regions, one for each metric I needed to display.   Now, new metrics need to be added and I want to avoid adding "hardcoded" region divs in the template.  I want to refactor this and create the required regions dynamically at startup time based on some configuration data.

So I have been looking at the latest Marionette release and in question "[Dynamically add regions to Marionette layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690683/dynamically-add-regions-to-marionette-layout)", Derick Bailey mentions that Marionette v1.0 supports dynamic regions in Layouts through addRegion(), as in:

```
var layout = new MyLayout();
layout.render()
layout.addRegion("someRegion", "#some-element");
layout.someRegion.show(new MyView());
```

I have tried that in my code (using Marionette 1.0.2) and I am not getting it to work.  I don't have a div with id="some-element" in my template and I suspect this could be the reason. I was hoping that Marionette would create that div itself.

Perhaps my expectation of what dynamically adding a region means is wrong.  So my first question is: when adding regions dynamically to a layout, must the element id passed in the addRegion() function already exist in the layout?

If so, then I am back to the problem of having to "burn" in the template those divs for the regions to attach themselves too.  My follow-up question is then: What is the best way of doing this in a  data-driven fashion?  Is it a matter of writing my own render() function so that the right set of divs get created?  Or perhaps providing my Layout with a model object that will contain data which the template can then iterate through to create the necessary divs?  How do we add regions dynamically to a Layout object if we don't know in advance how many regions we will actually need?

Answer (score 1):

Aa @aaronfay specified, we need to use jQuery to create the element on the page. Here is some sample code:

```
var layout = new MyLayout();
layout.render()
var regionName = "dynamicRegion"; 
layout.$el.append('<div id="'+regionName+'"></div>');
layout.addRegion("someRegion", "#"+regionName);
layout.someRegion.show(new MyView());
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to use jQuery (or similar) to create the element on the page. A Region expects the element to exist.

Otherwise, I believe your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690683/dynamically-add-regions-to-marionette-layout).