# Elegant way to append several views to a region in Marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view, marionette

Is there a more elegant way than the one below to append another view to a region? I'd like to append as many chat windows when a button is clicked, and destroy it when a button within the chat window is clicked.

The one below requires to keep track of an index per element:

```
var AppLayoutView = Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
  template: "#layout-view-template",

  regions: {
      wrapperChat : '#wrapper-chat'
  }
  appendView: function ( incremennt, newView ){
     this.$el.append( '<div id="view'+increment+'" >' ) ;
     this.regionManager.addRegion( 'view'+increment , '#view'+increment )
     this['view'+increment].show ( newView ) ;
  }
});

// ChatView
var ChatView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: "#chat-template"
});

// Layout
var LayoutView = new AppLayoutView();
LayoutView.render();

// Append View
LayoutView.wrapper.appendView(++index, new ChatView());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regions are designed to show a single View. Marionette's abstraction for repeating views is [`CollectionView`](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md), which renders an `ItemView` for each [Model](http://backbonejs.org/#Model) in a [Collection](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection).

You add or remove *Models* from the Collection;  Marionette handles the view updates for you.

If your `ChatView` already has a model, use that. If not, you could add a trivial model to abstract away the `index` variable.

```
// Collection for the Chat models. 
// If you already have Chat Collection/Models, use that. 
// If not, create a simple Collection and Models to hold view state, e.g.:
var chats = new Backbone.Collection();

// CollectionView "subclass"
var ChatCollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
  itemView: ChatView
})

// Add a single ChatCollectionView to your region
var chatsView = new ChatCollectionView({ collection: chats });
LayoutView.getRegion('wrapperChat').show();

// To add a ChatView, add a Model to the Collection
var nextChatId = 0;
chart.addChat(new Backbone.Model({ id: nextChatId++ }));

// To remove a chat, remove its model
chart.remove(0);
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20570284/creating-a-layout-that-accepts-a-variable-number-of-views-and-hence-regions?rq=1